# how to include apache active MQ jars in the installed WAS server library path

Tags: java, websphere, shared-libraries

I have to send message to active MQ where the application is deployed in WAS server. how to include apache active MQ jars in the installed WAS server library path

Answer (score 0):

See the [Associating shared libraries with servers](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tcws_sharedlib_server.html) topic in the Knowledge Center.